# Changing fonts in the Mate terminal application

Tags: terminal, freebsd, fonts, unicode, mate-desktop

How would I change the font of my terminal in FreeBSD to the Noto Sans font? I am interested in Noto's support for a wide variety of Unicode characters. I downloaded the font using the package manager and I changed my terminal settings to en_UTF-8. But some Unicode characters are not displaying (e.g. Ʌ which is u0245) it just shows up as \U+0245 in terminal. How would I configure the terminal so that Noto sans is the default font and certain characters like Ʌ show up in the terminal?

Comment: Which terminal application are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Mate desktop environment, so the default terminal for Mate.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using MATE with the default terminal emulator start the MATE Terminal and open the menu *Edit* - *Profile Preferences* - tab *General*, uncheck *Use the system fixed width font* and choose your desired font.